# Cannot find gem set when running rspec inside vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rspec

I'm trying to run rspec inside vim. However, instead of choosing the correct gemset(via rvm), vim defaults to the global gemset which causes the spec not to run. How do you set the rvm gemset in vim? (It works when running the command in the Iterm window)

vim command:

```
:!rspec spec
```

vim output:

```
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources 
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

shell returned 7
```

Comment: Your PATH in vim is wrong. Check which files are loaded for an non-interactive shell. (For bash put stuff in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`)

Answer (score -1):

After struggling for a while, this worked for me:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/zshenv /etc/zshrc
```